# Object Error in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to parse data from sheet1 into an array then printing it to another worksheet. I get an object required error, but from what I can gather from msdn is that my object types are wrong for the array but when I switch the array from string to variant I get a mismatch error instead. What can I do to fix the object required 424 error? Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Enter2_Click()
    'Define Variables
    Dim MatchRow As Integer
    Dim data() As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim dataInfo As String

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'Match Name To A Row
    MatchRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(RName.Value, Range("A1:A100"), 0)

    For i = 0 To 22
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Cells(MatchRow, i + 3).Select
        data = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ".")

        Worksheets("Reporting template").Activate
        Cells(20, 1).Select
        ActiveCells.Value = data(0)  'This is where the error pops up at
        ActiveCells.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCells.Value = data(1)
        ActiveCells.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCells.Value = data(2)
        ActiveCells.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCells.Value = data(3)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `ActiveCells` an object you have defined anywhere? Usually to refer to the active cell we use `ActiveCell`. No `s`.

Comment: Rofl I must have done that while copying and pasting. Thank you so much!